# JTidy issue with numbered list item

Tags: java, itext, pdf-generation, jtidy, numbered-list

I am facing a weird problem with **Numbered List Item** while generating pdf using `IText`. The serial number of the item list is not incremented by one when a `<br/>` tag is appended. consider the following example:

```
String withoutBrTag = "<html><head></head><body><p>this is order list</p>" +
                "        <br>" +
                "        <ol>" +
                "          <li>lafjad</li>" +
                "          <li>alsdfkjla </li>" +
                "          <li>asdflkjadslfkj</li>" +
                "        </ol>" +
                "        <br>" +
                "        <p>list item ended</p>&nbsp;"+
                "</body></html>";

String wihBrTag = "<html><head></head><body><p>this is order list</p>" +
                "        <br>" +
                "        <ol>" +
                "          <br>" +
                "          <li>lafjad</li>" +
                "          <br>" +
                "          <li>alsdfkjla </li>" +
                "          <br>" +
                "          <li>asdflkjadslfkj</li>" +
                "          <br>" +
                "        </ol>" +
                "        <br>" +
                "        <p>list item ended</p>&nbsp;"+
                "</body></html>";

Tidy tidy = new Tidy();
tidy.setXmlOut(true);
tidy.setQuiet(true);
tidy.setShowWarnings(false);

OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("test1.pdf");

ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(withBrTag.getBytes());

Document doc = tidy.parseDOM(inputStream, null);
inputStream.close();

ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
renderer.setDocument(doc, null);
renderer.layout();
renderer.createPDF(outputStream);
```

For the *String* `withBrTag` the output is:

```
this is order list

2. list item one
4. list item two
6. list item three

list item ended
```

Note the numbering - `2, 4, 6`! Each `<br/>` tag is parsed as `<li>` node while performing `tidy.parseDOM(inputStream, null)`. Therefore the numbering changes. **TIDY** parsed the `html` content in a wrong way that leads to the numbering issue.

But if I use the *String* `withoutBrTag` the generated output is as expected.

```
this is order list

1. list item one
2. list item two
3. list item three

list item ended
```

Can anyone explain why `<br/>` tag is considered as a `</li>` tag and how can this be solved?

*NOTE 1:* not only for `<br/>` tag the numbering changes but also for any of the `html` tag like - `<p>, <i>, <hr/>` tags. That means if any tag is added right before or after a `<li>` tag, it will affect the numbering.

*NOTE 2:* itextpdf-2.0.1 is used.

Comment: You'd better put a flyingsoucer tag, it's the main issue here.

Comment: If I remember correctly, **ol** is specified to contain a sequence of **li** elements. Thus, your **br** must not be there. And broken input implies arbitrary output.

Comment: @mkl I agree with you. **<ol>** should not contain html tag other than **<li>**. Since browser can render the *html* correctly why does **tidy** create arbitrary output?

Comment: If the html is incorrect, the output on some target programs might still be as desired (because those programs probably ignore the specific incorrectness in a very specific way). Nonetheless other target programs may fail in any manner when processing that html.